# xlwings doesn't write data in file.xlsm when running through excel

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, vba

I am trying to use xlwings for simple consolidation from several xls files.
For this, I have a all_files.xlsm file that contains a button with macros assigned to it. The macros looks like:

```
Sub check_data()
    RunPython ("import python_code; python_code.consolidation()")
End Sub
```

In same folder I have a file python_code.py with function "consolidation" inside.
I also use Workbook.set_mock_caller() in order to have an opportunity to run a code through python interface. It looks like:

```
def consolidation(file_path):
    *** smth to get the data I need ***
    ...
    *** after I got data ***
    Range('A1').table.clear_contents() #string1
    Range('A1').value = data #string2

def main():
    consolidation(file_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xl.Workbook.set_mock_caller(path_to_file)
    main()
```

The problem is that when I am running the script through the button in excel file last two strings (string1 and string2) -  Range('A1').table.clear_contents() and Range('A1').value = data doesn't work. Although the rest of the code works fine (however, it contains xlwing also). Moreover, if I run the script through the python interface using set mock caller, it works just fine, including string1 and string2 (marked in the code).

Any help and advices are really appreciated!

Comment: When you say "... doesn't work" - can you be more specific? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Sure, thanks.  I don't get any error messages. But it doesn't print result data and also doesn't clear  old results from the page.

Comment: Actually, I have transfered script from cloud to my local machine, and know I am able to se an error, when trying to perform through an excel button: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-9: ordinal not in range(128). And it still works absolutely fine when running through python and set_mock_caller

Comment: You must have a non-ascii character in there somewhere - could be a smart quote looking like ' or "... Clear cells or remove parts of the script until you pin it down. This is probably entirely to do with your data in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Barny, I found a solution. Thanks a lot for you quick reaction and for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found decision for my problem. For using xlwings in python you should import xlwings.bas in your excel file (see manual for xlwings). It turns out, that I imported it for this macros before I've updated xlwings. So I deleted this file and imported a new one. Everything works fine now.